# How to find the path to a file recursively using CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have placed some header files in a subdirectory next to CMakeLists.txt called "dependencies". I want to search this directory recursively to find a header file. I'm trying the below command, but it's not working:

```
find_path(ALLEGRO_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES "allegro*.h" PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command instead:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE ALLEGRO_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/allegro*.h")
```